# Regex for validating video url protocols (ex:rstp://)

Tags: regex, reactjs, video

I need to validate a video URL protocol that may have different protocols in a URL.I need to do it with Live stream URL and I can't predict which protocols are attached with video url

Comment: Your question is not a question. More Description with example  is needed and what have you tried ?

Comment: What protocols do you want to accept?

Comment: I need to accept protocol like  rtmp //  ,rstp:// etc.. .But I can't predict the exact protocol. User manually entering the url and I need to validate the url protocol .